# Why 'Index' object has no attribute 'month_name' (code stopped working for no reason after working smoothly)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, python-datetime

So, my code was working a few minutes ago, but for some reason despite it being the same code it stopped working and gave me  'Index' object has no attribute 'month_name' for this line

```
for i, month in enumerate(feature_df.index.month_name().unique(), 3):
  feature_df[month] = (feature_df.index.month == i+1).astype(int)
```

Note : the weird formatting for some stuff is because I'm using colab and it prints automatically.

```
"""

data_urls = {
  "2014": "https://sitewebbixi.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/docs/biximontrealrentals2014-f040e0.zip",
  "2015": "https://sitewebbixi.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/docs/biximontrealrentals2015-69fdf0.zip",
  "2016": "https://sitewebbixi.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/docs/biximontrealrentals2016-912f00.zip",
  "2017": "https://sitewebbixi.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/docs/biximontrealrentals2017-d4d086.zip",
  "2018": "https://sitewebbixi.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/docs/biximontrealrentals2018-96034e.zip",
  "2019": "https://sitewebbixi.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/docs/biximontrealrentals2019-33ea73.zip",
}

"""# Load the data"""

"""
Load all the data

We will need:
- the requests package to surf the web, 
- the io package to read the data stream from the response,
- the zipfile package to manipulate the archive.
"""
import io
import pandas as pd
import requests
import zipfile


df = None
for year, url in data_urls.items():
  print("Processing {}".format(year))
  # Load the url
  response = requests.get(url)
  # Read the archive from the response
  archive = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(response.content))
  # Loop over all the files in the archive
  for file in archive.namelist():
    # Check that we are looking at one of the files we want
    if not archive.getinfo(file).is_dir() and "Station" not in file:
      print("Loading data from: {}".format(file))
      # We will load the start_date column only to save on memory use
      try:
        current_length = len(df)
        df = df.append(
          pd.read_csv(archive.open(file), usecols=["start_date"]),
          ignore_index=True, 
        )
      except:
        current_length = 0
        df = pd.read_csv(archive.open(file), usecols=["start_date"])
      print(" > {} rows processed".format(len(df) - current_length))
  response.close()

"""# Convert to datetime"""

#This converts our dataframe to datetime
df["start_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start_date"])

df.describe()

df.info()

"""#Adding values that will help with the project"""

#This adds values for each date (without the hour)
df["date"] = df["start_date"].dt.date

#This adds values for each year from 2014 to 2019 to the dataframe
df["year"] = df["start_date"].dt.year

#This adds values for each day of the week to the dataframe
df["dayoftheweek"] = df["start_date"].dt.dayofweek

#This adds values for each day of the year to the dataframe
df["dayoftheyear"] = df["start_date"].dt.dayofyear

#This adds values for each month to the dataframe 
df["month"] = df["start_date"].dt.month

#This adds values for each week of the year to the dataframe
df["week"] = df["start_date"].dt.week

#This adds values for each hour (in a day) to the dataframe 
df["houroftheday"] = df["start_date"].dt.hour

"""# Visualizations to see the trends"""

#Get simple dataframes for each type of data in order to graph them
year_df = df["year"].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()
dayoftheweek_df = df["dayoftheweek"].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()
dayoftheyear_df = df["dayoftheyear"].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()
week_df = df["week"].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()
month_df = df["month"].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()
houroftheday_df = df["houroftheday"].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()
date_df = df["date"].value_counts(normalize=True).sort_index()

"""##Trends for each **year**"""

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=[16,9], dpi=300)
plt.bar(year_df.index, year_df.values)
plt.show()

"""Usage goes higher each year, so that needs to be taken into account.

##Trends for each **day of the week**
"""

plt.figure(figsize=[16,9], dpi=300)
plt.bar(dayoftheweek_df.index, dayoftheweek_df.values)
plt.show()

"""In the graph above, 0 stands for Monday, 1 for Tuesday, so on and so forth.<br> So, BIXI usage is smaller during Saturday and Sunday. That seems to be a factor.

##Trends for each **month**
"""

plt.figure(figsize=[16,9], dpi=300)
plt.bar(month_df.index, month_df.values)
plt.show()

"""The trend is lower in the months where BIXI ends/starts and when it gets colder. Usage peaks in summer.

##Trends for each **day of the year**
"""

plt.figure(figsize=[16,9], dpi=300)
plt.bar(dayoftheyear_df.index, dayoftheyear_df.values)
plt.show()

"""The trend is similar to the months except, that on certain weekends (it's every seven days) we have a few drops.

## Trends per date
"""

plt.figure(figsize=[16,9], dpi=300)
plt.bar(date_df.index, date_df.values)
plt.show()

"""This is essentially a combination of the trend per year and the trend per day of the year together, but it uses the actual dates.

##Trends for each **week**
"""

plt.figure(figsize=[16,9], dpi=300)
plt.bar(week_df.index, week_df.values)
plt.show()

"""This trend is pretty much the monthly trend but with weeks (we see how the changes in usage happen in more detail)

## Trends for each **hour**
"""

plt.figure(figsize=[16,9], dpi=300)
plt.bar(houroftheday_df.index, houroftheday_df.values)
plt.show()

"""As we can see here, there's more bixi usage around rush hour periods (8 am & 3-6 pm), so we need to take that into account, since it is an important factor.

#Building the model
To build the model, we first need to set the target vector, then create the feature matrix and finally initializing the model that will make our predictions.

##Target vector
"""

target_df = df.groupby("date").size()
target_df

"""## Feature matrix
Here we will create the feature matrix
"""

"""###Feature #1 : Day of the week"""

feature_df = pd.get_dummies(df.groupby("date").first(), columns=["dayoftheweek"], prefix="", prefix_sep="").loc[:,["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]]
feature_df

"""###Feature #2 : Month of the year"""

for i, month in enumerate(feature_df.index.month_name().unique(), 3):
  feature_df[month] = (feature_df.index.month == i+1).astype(int)

feature_df

"""##Dropping redundant columns"""

#This removes Monday and April, they will serve as our baseline
feature_matrix = feature_df.drop(columns=["0", "April"])

"""## Choosing a model
The model will be initialized and then used to make some predictions
"""

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

model = LinearRegression()
model

model.fit(feature_matrix , target_df)

model.coef_

model.intercept_

parameters = pd.Series(model.coef_, index=feature_matrix.columns)
parameters

"""#Predicting"""

#June 4th 2016 was a Tuesday
feature_matrix.loc["2019-06-04"]

feature_matrix.loc["2019-06-04"].values.reshape(1, -1)

model.predict(feature_matrix.loc["2019-06-04"].values.reshape(1, -1))[0]

"""##Quick plot for the initial features"""

plt.figure(figsize=[21,9], dpi=300)
plt.plot(feature_matrix.index, target_df, feature_matrix.index, model.predict(feature_matrix))
plt.show()

# 2016 only, since it seems to be the most accurate
from matplotlib import dates as mdate
plt.figure(figsize=[21,9], dpi=300)
plt.plot(feature_matrix.index, target_df, feature_matrix.index, model.predict(feature_matrix))
plt.xlim(left=mdate.datestr2num("2016-04-15"), right=mdate.datestr2num("2016-12-31"))
plt.show()

# 2019 only, since it seems to be the least accurate
from matplotlib import dates as mdate
plt.figure(figsize=[21,9], dpi=300)
plt.plot(feature_matrix.index, target_df, feature_matrix.index, model.predict(feature_matrix))
plt.xlim(left=mdate.datestr2num("2019-04-15"), right=mdate.datestr2num("2019-10-31"))
plt.show()

"""## Initial RMSE"""

import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import resample
np.random.seed(1)
uncertainty = np.std([model.fit(*resample(feature_matrix, target_df)).coef_ for i in range(1000)], 0)
params = pd.Series(uncertainty, index=feature_matrix.columns)
params

"""###Check RMSE for 2016 & 2019

####2019
"""

import math
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

#Use all data and then check 2019 predictions
error = mean_squared_error(model.predict(feature_matrix.loc[feature_matrix.index.year == 2019]), target_df.loc[target_df.index.year == 2019])
print(math.sqrt(error))

# Retrain while leaving out 2018, and then try to predict 2018
model.fit(feature_matrix.loc[feature_matrix.index.year < 2019], target_df.loc[target_df.index.year < 2019])
error = mean_squared_error(model.predict(feature_matrix.loc[feature_matrix.index.year == 2019]), target_df.loc[target_df.index.year == 2019])
print(math.sqrt(error))

"""####2016"""

import math
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error

#Use all data and then check 2016 predictions
error = mean_squared_error(model.predict(feature_matrix.loc[feature_matrix.index.year == 2016]), target_df.loc[target_df.index.year == 2016])
print(math.sqrt(error))

# Retrain while leaving out 2016, and then try to predict 2016
model.fit(feature_matrix.loc[feature_matrix.index.year < 2016], target_df.loc[target_df.index.year < 2016])
error = mean_squared_error(model.predict(feature_matrix.loc[feature_matrix.index.year == 2016]), target_df.loc[target_df.index.year == 2016])
print(math.sqrt(error))

"""As the graph showed, 2016 is currently more accurate than 2019

#Feature #3: Day of the year'''
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your index column has `datetime.date` objects. You have to first convert it Pandas series, then apply map to convert it to `pd._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp` and then you shall be able to use `month_name()` and `month` on it.

Here is the code snippet you can try:-

```
for i, month in enumerate(pd.Series(feature_df.index).map(lambda x:pd._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp(x)).dt.month_name().unique(), 3):

    x = (pd.Series(pd.Series(feature_df.index).map(lambda x:pd._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp(x)).dt.month == (i+1))).astype(int)
    x.index = feature_df.index
    feature_df[month]=x
feature_df
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I am confused as to how it managed to run without that fix at a certain point.

Comment: May be you had some cache variable in jupyter (Some fix you tried in some other cell and later deleted that cell). But when you restart kernel it gives you error as the cache gets cleared. Happens with me. So I always restart and run all cell at regular interval while developing code. Its just a guess though.

Comment: I think the fix may have caused another error. I get a key error in the next part that uses the feature_matrix (which is feature_df with 2 dropped columns) : It's in this line : ```feature_matrix.loc["2019-06-04"]```